# Wifi doesn't want to connect

Tags: networking, wireless

I got a problem on my Ubuntu 18.04 with the WiFi. I can see all the WiFi networks around me, but when I try to connect the PC is trying to do for about about 30 seconds (there is the circle waiting logo) and it gives up. It even doesn't ask me the password.

What could be the problem? (what kind of information you'll need).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try moving closer to the access point.

Answer (score 0):

try running following in the terminal:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and wait for a while and then:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Read More here: [Network Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager)

Comment: I will try later.
Actually I could connect if I select "Connect to hidden network" and enter all the parameters myself. Even if the network is not hidden, and visible (from Linux and Windows).
There is another network (from RPi) that Windows can see but my Ubuntu cannot. 
I'll see if restarting the network of my computer will work